# Trigger pipeline job from other and wait for it on next stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to execute pipeline B from pipeline A , do some work and than come back and wait until B is finished.
something like this:

```
pipeline
{
   stages {
        stage ('Init') {
            steps {
              job_b = build (job:"my_name", wait: false)
            }
        }
        stage ('step 2')
        {
         steps
         {
           ....do some work
         }
        stage ('step3'){
         steps
         {
            job_b.waitUtilFinish()
          }
       }
}
```

I familiar with parallel but I don't want to use it because blue Ocean view in parallel and I have the entire pipeline to do until checking the other job

Answer (score 0):

You can merge 'Init' and 'Step 3' stages into a unique a stage and use `parallel` directive:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        parallel {
            stage ('step 1') {
                steps {
                    job_b = build (job:"my_name", wait: true)
                }
            }
            stage ('step 2') {
                steps {                        
                    ....do some work
                }
            }  ​
        ​}
   ​ }
}
```